# How to get non matching strings from two sets in JAVA?

Tags: java, list, collections, set

How should i get non matching elements only one time?
My Code is as follow:

```
Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(); //consist 90 elements
Set<Object> hashSet2 = new HashSet<Object>();// consist 9 elements
for (String string : hashSet ) {
                for(Object obj: hashSet2){
                     if(obj.equals(string)){
                         System.out.println(string + "\t is present in tracking     sheet");     
                     }
                     if(!obj.equals(string)){
                          System.out.println(string + "\t is not sheet");

                     }
                    }

         }
```

Using first if() i'm able to get elements that are in both sets.
Using second if() i'm getting results all elements in first set.

Output: 
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet

```
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet    
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
GBS-40747    is not in sheet    
GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is present in tracking sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-40747    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is present in tracking sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-35562    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is present in tracking sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    GBS-39321    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    0.8 build    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is present in tracking sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-39421    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-38455    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is present in tracking sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-40695    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-38467    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
    GBS-41315    is not in sheet
```

**Thanks everyone for providing their comments and solutions. I have selected one as an accepted answer (KISS: Keep it short and simple)(would have selected more if permitted :-)), but a lot were helpful.**

Comment: set any Boolean value inside loop, if it is `true` then print the `System.out.println(string + "\t is not sheet");` statement.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go for this:

```
Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(); // consist 90 elements
Set<Object> hashSet2 = new HashSet<Object>(); // consist 9 elements
for (String string : hashSet) {
    if (hashSet2.contains(string)) {
        System.out.println(string + "\t is present in tracking     sheet");
    } else {
        System.out.println(string + "\t is not sheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is simple and short. (KISS:- Keep it simple and short)

Comment: Sorry, `<brainFart>`what was I thinking `</brainFart>`

Answer (score 1):

try using a boolean which can set to true if found.  I assume that you can `break` when you have found the `String`

```
for (String string : hashSet ) {

            boolean found = false;
            for(Object obj: hashSet2){
                 if(obj.equals(string)){
                     found = true;
                     break;
                 }
            }
            if (found) {
               System.out.println(string + "\t is present in tracking sheet");
            } else {
               System.out.println(string + "\t is not sheet");
            }

}
```

Comment: @SugatMankar if the answer helped you, for love of god, accept it as your answer to show you care about others effort to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html) library for disjunction(). Which will return a collection that contains the elements that are not shared between two collections.

```
Collection nonMatchingSet = CollectionUtils.disjunction(hashSet , hashSet2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily suing `Set`.

```
  Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
  Set<Object> hashSet2 = new HashSet<>();
  hashSet.add("1");
  hashSet.add("2");
  hashSet.add("4") ;
  hashSet2.add("1");
  hashSet2.add("3");
  hashSet2.add("5");
  Set<Object> temp=new HashSet<>();
  temp.addAll(hashSet2);
  hashSet2.removeAll(hashSet); // remove common elements
  hashSet.removeAll(temp);// remove common elements 
  hashSet2.addAll(hashSet); // add unique values sets
  System.out.println(hashSet2);
```

Out put:

```
  [3, 2, 5, 4]
```

Comment: how is my answer now?

Comment: @KickButtowski it is fine now

Comment: thank you for your correction and helping me to be better thank you

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
   List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "4", "5");

    Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>(list1);
    Set<String> hashSet2 = new HashSet<>(list2);

    hashSet.retainAll(hashSet2);

    Set<String> totallSet =   Stream.of(list1,list2)
                                .flatMap( string -> string.stream())
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    totallSet.removeAll(hashSet);

    totallSet.forEach(i -> System.out.print(" " + i));
```

Output:

```
3,4,5
```

Comment: You missed the real question.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera could you tell me what it is?

Comment: OP's list like `{1,2,3}` and `{1,2,4,5}` then answer should be `{3,4,5}`, and your answer not give that.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera is it better now?

Comment: @TheLostMind I am sure you are pulling my legs big time :p old friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, in this code all items in hashset that has equals object in hashset2 remove from hashset:

```
    hashSet.removeAll(hashSet2);
    for (String s : hashSet) {
        System.out.println(s + " is not in sheet !");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj` is instance of `Object` class. and your are doing here `obj.equals(string)` means your are calling `Object's equals method` and this equals method checking `identity check`. But for finding similarity you have check `equality check`.

Answer (score 0):

`hashSet.retainAll` method also help you remove from hashSet2 all items that are not in the hasSet so after running the following statment:

```
hashSet.retainAll(hashSet2);
```

hashSet2 will only contain the elements exist in hashSet. which they are present in tracking sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
package Example;

import java.util.*;

public class CopyOfSample2 {


public static void main(String s[]){

        Set<String> set1=new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> set2=new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> difference=new HashSet<String>(set1);

        set1.add("1");
        set1.add("5");
        set1.add("2");

        set2.add("3");
        set2.add("2");
        set2.add("1");


        difference.removeAll(set2);
        System.out.println("Difference" +difference);
    }
}
```